# Encoding.Default is not the same as no encoding in File.ReadAllText?

Tags: .net, encoding, file-io

(Sorry if this is a dupe)

I've just spent a long time trying to read a text file correctly.

Having started with `File.ReadAllText(path)` and getting screwed-up characters, I tried several variants of `File.ReadAlltext(path, Encoding)` after which I got bogged down trying to analyse my input files to work out which byte was the problem, etc.

In desperation I tried `File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.Default)`, which worked!

I'm now struggling to understand why the default value is apparently only the default value if you specify it.

(My cut-down test string was `+4433ç`, I saved it in notepad as ANSI - though with Swiss French regional settings...)

Comment: Note that Encoding.Default shouldn't be considered the "default" encoding - it's the (non unicode!) encoding for the system's default *codepage*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Encoding.Default is the system's ANSI codepage.

What File.ReadAllText does if you don't specify an encoding is this:

- First it checks whether there's a byte order mark (UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32). If there is, it uses the encoding specified in the byte order mark.
- Otherwise, it uses UTF-8.

So the only way to get the system's ANSI codepage is to explicitly specify Encoding.Default.

Comment: File.ReadAllText doesn't check for byte order mark. It will always use UTF-8, if you don't specify encoding. This is confirmed by both Reflector and the .NET reference source.

Comment: Jivko, I don't think your comment is correct. ReadAllText without an encoding calls ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8), but the internal stream used by ReadAllText will read the BOM if present and replace the Encoding.UTF8 with the detected encoding. This is because detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks is set to true in the StreamReader constructor.

Answer (score 3):

UTF8 is the real default and it is only used when automatic detection do not found any encoding. So the BOM is more important. See details below:

`ReadAllText(string path)` - MSDN: "This method attempts to automatically detect the encoding"

`ReadAllText(string path, Encoding encoding)` - MSDN: "This method attempts to automatically detect the encoding"

From Reflector tool: `ReadAllText(path)` is the same as `ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8)`, because `ReadAllText(path)` just calls `ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8)`. Both methods creates StreamReader in this way:

```
public StreamReader(string path, Encoding encoding) : this(path, encoding, true, 0x400)
{
}
```

This means that it creates `StreamReader(string path, Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, int bufferSize)` with detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks set to true. This means that if the Byte Order Mark (BOM) is present it will use encoding from BOM, if BOM is not present then it will use provided encoding. If BOM is not present and encoding is not provided then it will use UTF8. So the **UTF8** is the real default in this case, but remember that BOM is more important than suggested encoding.

```
// bom.txt is the file with BOM present. nobom.txt - witout BOM
File.ReadAllText("bom.txt");                     // use BOM
File.ReadAllText("bom.txt", Encoding.UTF8);      // use BOM
File.ReadAllText("bom.txt", Encoding.Default);   // use BOM
File.ReadAllText("nobom.txt");                   // use UTF-8
File.ReadAllText("nobom.txt", Encoding.UTF8);    // use UTF-8
File.ReadAllText("nobom.txt", Encoding.Default); // use system's ANSI codepage
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to override the BOM, so that the Encoding.whatever becomes the priority?

Comment: @DanW, you can try using `new StreamReader("brokenFile.txt", Encoding.whatever, false)`. But in this case it will probably treat BOM as text - so you will get strange characters on the beginning. Be sure what you are doing because, when BOM is set, then it is usually set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN, about the string ReadAllText(string path) overload:

> This method attempts to automatically detect the encoding of a file

So No, it is not the same as using the Default Encoding